# Locust io and javascript

Tags: javascript, locust

I need help with the following, I am trying to get a get from a page (it brings a client information), but said page has a javascript that is executed to monitor, the idea is that when I do the get I also execute said script.

I have looked for some solutions but none is what I need. Is there a way to execute the javascript that is on the web when making the request?

thanks for te help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Locust does not run javascript, it is not a real browser.

The best way to work around this is by reimplementing any client-side logic you need in Python (in your locust file).

If your javascript is very complex, you could try remote-controlling an actual browser using WebDriver. It is prohibitively resource-intensive on the load gen side and quite unstable (like WebDriver always is), but for low-load scenarios it can be done.

https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/examples/webdriver_ex.py

But the first option is the best in 99% of cases.